# Present perfect tense vs Present perfect continous tense

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

> 1. I **have eaten** food for two hours.

> 2. I **have been eating** food for two hours.

Are both sentences correct? Do they mean same thing that, "They started eating two hours back and eating even now" ? If not, what is the difference in meaning between them?

Comment: (1) would be OK with some other verbs ('I have walked for two hours', for example), but I can't imagine anyone actually saying 'I have eaten food for two hours'.

Comment: So Is  1)I have walked for two hours and 2)I have been walking for two hours  same?? Do they mean they started walking two hours back and walking even now??

Comment: 'They started walking two hours back and _are_ walking even now' (or, better, 'are still walking'). Yes.

Answer (score -2):

The prepositional phrase which functions as an adverbial of time of the type *for some identified period of time* is not used with the tense structure of the Present Perfect tense in the literary speech with the verbs of accomplishment. This adverbial of time is a marker of the Present Perfect Continuous tense in such case. To put it simply.
Such usage happens sometimes in the vocal speech rarely.
If you want to convey such an idea you may use other grammatical structures. For example, *Sorry, I am fed up. We have already spent several hours eating*.

Why the sentence **I have eaten food for two hours* is ungrammatical totally in the literary English? The verb *eat* has got the two meanings in the literary language: 1. *chew food and swallow it*, 2. *have a meal*. The major test for the correctness of usage for the Present Perfect tense is that we can often construct a sentence with the linking verb *be* or with other present-tense grammatical constructions to show the real (or imaginary) result implied in the sentence with the Present Perfect tense. If the test failed, the sentence is ungrammatical. The example from textbooks, *Utopia has invaded Fantasia*. Test, *Utopia is at war against Fantasia*. The test passes. The sentence is grammatical.

In case of *I have eaten food for two hours* any possible test fails.

There are rare examples of such sentence in some textbooks of AmE. The reason is that the verb *eat* bears an informal meaning of *getting one's fill* in such examples. The test passes for such sentences as *Someone is fed up* usually. Though, no one sentence with the verb *eat* containes the adverbial prepositional phrase of the type *for some identified period of time* in these examples too.

Comment: How is an English language learner supposed to understand that?

Comment: Agree. It is not easy to explain these things in simple words.

Comment: This is a simple variant for learners.

Comment: But, of course I've eaten food for two hours.  That's a traditional way to celebrate Thanksgiving.  It so happens that I haven't done that in the past few years, but, like anyone who has enjoyed the occasional feast, *I have done it*, and possibly for even longer periods of time.  A more important distinction here is that "I have eaten" lacks the immediacy of "I have been eating".  In short, "I have been eating" implies that I am still eating; "I have eaten" implies that I am finished.

Comment: Sorry for delaying. Now ball's on your court. What you've written is really intresting, but it'll take  space to write you back. Give me some time to mull over an answer that'd be short enough.

Comment: Thanksgiving proclamations were made mostly by church leaders in New England (USA) up until 1682 (XVII century) . The Present Perfect Continuous Tense begins to be widely used from the XVIII-th century.The majority of English speaking persons nowdays consider that the sentence *I have eaten for two hours* doesn't make any sense at all, numerous confirmations of that opinion can be found without any effort on the Web.

Comment: Proclamations?  Thanksgiving is celebrated every year, even without my participation.  Regardless, I've taken the time to show you several ordinary, unremarkable examples of the present perfect construction.  Unsurprisingly, no one (including you) has remarked.  Also unsurprisingly, "have eaten" occurs about ten times more often than "have been eating".  Why bother with opinion when it's easy to reference [fact](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+eaten%2Chave+been+eating)? You should also be able to see for yourself how often "for *some time period*" follows "have eaten".

Comment: In fact, @KateBunting, I'd love to see if you've another tuppence to add, now that a relevant context has been established.

Comment: @Gary Botnovcan What for so many words, and ngram having been checked out as well? Why not just to write the main phrase for the description of Thanksgiving festivities, I mean *Thanksgiving dinner*, to establish an essential guide for browsing on the Web actually?

Comment: I never said that _I have eaten food for two hours_ was ungrammatical. I just suggested  that it was an unlikely sentence, and that _eat_ was not the best verb with which to demonstrate the difference between the tenses. That is why I used _walk_ instead.

Comment: @Gary Botnovan  Now it's your turn. Do you know such a verb phrase *to eat turky* ? It is really possible to say *They have eaten turky for two hours*, but it is not possible to say * They have eaten food for two hours*. The verb phrases *to eat turky* and *eat food* are different with own grammatical features. The first is a verb of state , the second - of accomplishment and achievement.

Comment: Thanks, @Kate.  I appreciate it.  In case it wasn't clear, I didn't ask for my own sake.  I just didn't want it to risk the appearance of putting words in your mouth unfairly, on the off chance that anyone might have been paying attention.

Comment: @Gary Botnovan Sorry, it was me who wrote it

Comment: No, @kngram, I wasn't thanking you.  To you I'd need to say something along the lines that how specific the direct object may be (and even whether one is explicitly supplied at all) makes no difference to the grammar of this verb.  Whatever you're looking at, it isn't grammar and it doesn't seem to be English.  But, I wasn't going to bother.  I simply wanted to thank her and then drop this exchange entirely.  It's quite clear that you're not paying any attention to it.

Comment: @ Gary Botnovcan Pls, don't be too serious on the question that is very simple actually. Special object, not so special object... What is it? I have explained everything above. So, thank you too for the discussion.